# Contents of bin folder after publishing .NET project to an MSI file - where will the image go?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-installer, publishing, bin

I am working on a WinForms application which uses a flatbed scanner (in conjunction with PixTools library).

Currently when running in debug mode (unpublished), when the application code scans the image, it stores the image file .jpg in the bin folder of the project (C:...\Source\winapp\bin). My code then has to manually move this file using File.Move() to the directory where I want it to end up.

However I am thinking that when I publish the application to install on another machine, this bin folder won't exist. I am wondering where the application is likely to store the .jpg from the scanner in this case so I can write the code in advance. For instance, will the image appear somewhere in the installation folder which is selected when installing application the first time round?

Thanks for any advice/help

C

Comment: As a side note, you might want to clarify your original question - you've said using an MSI file, but the comments make it clear you're actually publishing via ClickOnce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Create/Store your image file(.jpg) into your Debug/Release folder which is the path from where your Application exe runs.

The following code gives you the path from where your Application is running:

```
String  ApplicationFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "");
```

The Above code returns the path similar to

```
SolutionFolder/ProjectFolder/bin/Debug(or)Release
```

So you can target your code to retrieve the image from the above location as it is avaialable even after deplyoing/Installing the Application on client PC.

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar. I used your code and when I run within Visual Studio in Debug or Release mode, I get the intended results. I wrote a test app which only has a button which, when clicked, displays a message box with the string contents in it. I then tried publishing and installing the app on my other laptop to see what would appear. The string which appears is C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\0TZ6ROAO.PJG\WXB5LK32.P9W\wind...ti_82361c8a74b... etc. Is this to be expected and do you think this is where the image will be stored instead of the bin folder when installed on another machine?

Comment: Please see above Sudhakar. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: no problem, "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\0TZ6ROAO.PJG\WXB5LK32.P9W\wind...ti_82361c8a‌​74b... etc" is it the path where you have installed your application if yes then your image will be saved in same folder and it works.

Comment: I actually just copied my app's setup.exe file to a folder on the desktop called test but it appears to have used the C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\0TZ6ROAO.PJG\WXB5LK32.P9W\wind...ti_82361c8‌​a‌​74b... etc folder to install automatically. This directory also contains some other files such as the Application file, a couple of Manifest Files, XML config and CDF-MS file so in short, yes i think this is where the application has ultimately been installed. Thanks again, marking your initial response as the answer :)